# AdMob показывает тестовый баннер, но не показывает рекламу

Tags: android, admob

Ребятки, помогите... уже 2 недели бьюсь с этой проблемой. на эмуляторах разных версий ведройда и разных разрешений экрана, тестовый баннер показывается как надо, но стоит залить апк-шку на реальный девайс, как он не хочет показывать ни один баннер. Писем с адмоба никаких не приходило, акк забанить не могли.
такой вот логкат валится в эмуляторе:

```
 05-03 08:07:44.032 798-798/ru.xxx.xxx I/Ads: Starting ad request.
05-03 08:07:45.572 798-798/ru.xxx.xxx W/Ads: Loading already in progress, saving this object for future refreshes.
05-03 08:07:58.812 798-798/ru.xxx.xxx I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
05-03 08:07:58.922 798-798/ru.xxx.xxx I/Ads: Ad finished loading.
```

а вот такой на реальных девайсах

```
05-03 13:17:23.388 28142-28142/ru.xxx.xxx I/Ads: Starting ad request.
05-03 13:17:23.983 28142-28142/ru.xxx.xxx W/Ads: Loading already in progress, saving this object for future refreshes.
05-03 13:17:34.748 28142-28247/ru.xxx.xxx W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
05-03 13:17:34.749 28142-28142/ru.xxx.xxx W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

пробовал разные подключения к инету - вайфай, 3г, но исход один. еще раз повторюсь, что на акк адмоба я захожу спокойно, писем от них не было, пробовал создавать другие баннеры.

код активности

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdsController {


private static final String BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID = "xxx";
AdView bannerAd;
InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    // Create a gameView and a bannerAd AdView
    View gameView = initializeForView(new RunawayCat(this), config);
    setupAds();

    // Define the layout
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.addView(gameView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

    layout.addView(bannerAd, params);

    setContentView(layout);


}


public void setupAds() {
    bannerAd = new AdView(this);
    bannerAd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    
    bannerAd.setAdUnitId(BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID);
    bannerAd.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
    AdRequest ad = builder.build();
    builder.addTestDevice("xxxx");
    bannerAd.loadAd(ad);
}


@Override
public void showBannerAd() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bannerAd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            AdRequest ad = builder.build();
            bannerAd.loadAd(ad);
        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: Создайте другой `Ads Unit Id` и попробуйте с ним. Проверьте манифест, проверьте сервисы, проверьте правильность `Ads Unit Id`

Comment: ну я же писал, что создавал уже несклько баннеров с разным ИД, не помогает это... даже пакет переименовывал по всякому

Comment: На других устройствах пробовали?

Comment: Добавьте код активити и лейаута, может быть ошибка. Плюс еще вопрос, только ли на свое девайсе тестировали или на других тоже?

Comment: код добавил, у меня 3 девайса, тестировал на всех. и не только под своим акком гугла. может ли быть такой вариант, что реклама будет показываться только после публикации в маркете? должна ли вообще вылезать реклама во время отладки? пробовал добавлять устройства через addTestDevice(), но тоже тщетно.

Comment: я попробовал удалить акк гугла с телефона и... баннер загрузился! почему с аккаунтом гугла он не грузится?